# How much old termite damage is acceptable?

Tags: walls, framing, termite

Renovating a house. We confirmed with a pest company that there was a prior termite infestation but no current termite infestation. We are replacing some baseboards and I saw evidence of the old infestation and cut out some drywall to have a closer look. There are no issues with the wall but obvious termite damage on the bottom plate of this exterior wall. How risky would it be to just cover it up with some drywall and continue the baseboard project or do I need to hit pause/are we in a more drastic situation. The damage does not appear to cross through the full width of each floor plate.

[image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: I added a comment up here, since it wasn't part of the process, but get this right, this is most likely a bearing wall. After you get the floor done well then you can get about 10-2X4 to temp. hold the wall up to do the other work, It is actually easy, just tedious.  Here is a video from This Old House on the type of shoring to use. It may not even require cutting the studs to length. I have used this method and it really goes in fast and picks up a lot of weight.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZsS_4HiHT8    It is all in the first few minutes of the video the rest is not applicable.

Comment: Glad to se you got the drywall cut a little higher. With the video link in the prior comment and get the wall shored up about 1 ft away from the outside wall, you could take out the whole plate, cutting the rotted stud bottoms off first with a circular saw which will cut about 1/2 way through. That will establish a straight, square cut to follow the rest of the depth with an oscillating saw. Remove those cutoffs and the bad plate will practically lift out. Set the new lower plate in place, nail it down, then drive in the upper plate and release the temporary wall. The nail off the bottoms.

Comment: Since my shoring wall will be sitting on perpendicular floor joists shouldn’t I build a second shoring wall directly below in the basement so that the load transfer goes directly to the basement floor and not entirely to the joists? If that’s what I need to do what is a good way to ensure my to support walls are exactly on top of each other without drilling through my nice oak floors?

Comment: @Chris yes, you should have a 2nd wall in the basement to take the weight of the wall on the first floor. Odds are good that this is specified in the TOH video in the first comment (though I haven't watched _this_ specific one, I've watched enough TOH to know that they will ensure temp walls line up all the way from the floor requiring work to the lowest level in the house).

Comment: What about the damage under my front door. I assume the plate runs under that too? See new photo

Comment: Help me get the whole "picture".... you have a basement, the first floor where the pictures of the damaged plate are, and perhaps a second floor? If there is no second floor, and the reason I asked you made sure the joists are in great shape was so you could shore up only the level where the work is needed. Walls are cantilevered quite often when building a house up to 2 feet. A 1 foot offset will work on its own, but if you feel you need to do the basement too.... This was also assuming a single floor house.

Comment: Two story house With an unfinished basement with exposed ceiling joists directly beneath this area so building a second support wall would be straightforward I assume

Comment: New photo added showing same side of house from the basement view

Comment: Since there is a floor above the one with the damage, It may take more than 10 - 2X4s. you will need enough to place each "prop" or angled stud so they will be somewhere about 16 to 20" apart at the top. If there is a bathroom over the area, more shoring for sure. If there is a bedroom over the area it will not be so critical.

Answer (score 6):

The plate should be replaced. The stud bottoms are seriously affected too. If possible, investigate the damage in the crawlspace too. The repairs may need to start there. Termites, in most cases enter from the ground and start eating their way up.

Not knowing what the condition of the rim joist or the joist ends for that matter, all I can suggest is what I see in your pictures. The walls can be temporarily supported by another wall added to the inside so the plate can be removed without the wall dropping anymore. The damaged studs may only need 1 1/2" cut off the bottoms to get back to solid wood, then when the plates go back in, they can go back in doubled to make up what has been cut off the studs.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the crawl space and all the elements down there like rim joists, etc. The exterior wall is acting like a giant beam, but when a giant load is placed on it , it will crush those studs, plate, etc. causing cracks in the wall board.

Comment: Can I replace the seal plate in sections or does it need to be 112 foot continuous piece for the entire damaged area

Comment: You can replace it in sections as small as 4 feet, but larger the better for the actual sill plate. The "filler plate" can be smaller sections like 4 feet long but do not let the joints in the lower run of plate line up with the joints with the upper. I would not hold my breath on what the plywood subfloor looks like under the plate. Termites are attracted to moisture. If the wood was bone dry, it would be less attractive to the pests.  I say that since windows are there in the area, and a leaky window may be the culprit to bring the termites there. Landscaping close to the siding will is bad

Comment: Yes that’s probably it. We replaced all the windows since this termite damage happened and we cut down two trees that were near the house so hopefully we’ve addressed that part of the issue at least.

Comment: The sill plate needs to be bolted down, no exceptions, as per code. Depending on where you are located it may need additional bolts for high wind conditions or seismic loading.

Comment: Earlier I did realize I used the wrong term for the bottom or sole plate, calling it the sill plate.  Speaking of the sill plate now that is on top of the foundation, absolutely, it will need to be bolted down at least, should the damage go down that far. Usually, sill plates, real sill plates, not what I mistakenly called sill plates are either pressure treated to resist pests or at least regular framing set on top of a layer of copper to deter termites. That's not much protection, but it what was used back in the day, possibly still these days.

Comment: Inspected the crawlspace. Plywood subfloor looks OK but won’t know until we remove the sole plates And have a look from above. Some minor damage to about 6 inch section of the rim joist assume I could just add some blocking in between the perpendicular floor joists and take care of that that way?

Comment: If you are certain that is all there is a block will do. If you take a scratch awl or ice pick down with you, stick it in what is known to be solid wood and compare it with the areas that have a small bit of VISIBLE damage. It may give you a better idea of the damage you don't see. Either way, it is better to cover more area in your repair when you are working a "one sided" view of the damage A BIG plus if none of the joist ends are affected. Please confirm.

Comment: Gave all the visible rim joists a good whack with hammer, everything seems solid minus the one 6” area that butts up to the rotted end of the floor joist. I actually think this was water not termites. No visible termite damage really at all from the crawl space/ basement view. I think the primary termite issue is on the first floor at that sole plate. Assume nonissue if I install rim joist blocking across full length of house, just for peace of mind?

Comment: Yes that will work. Typically rim joists are only one 2X on edge. With the sole plate being a minimum of 3 1/2" adding the row you speak of will pick up the width of the sole plate above very handily. Now if I may make one last suggestion regarding the added blocking... LVL (laminated veneer lumber) is much much less prone to shrinkage than dimensional lumber. It is more costly but it is stable. One hint on the installation of the blocks. Do not cut them really snug on the length, you may need to rip them to width. Make sure the height is snug, more than snug, so they need to be driven (Cont.)

Comment: (Cont.) in, using a scrap block to protect the driven end, setting the block in vertically, driving it in and "rotating it into place as you drive it in.  Another approach for the same purpose is after ripping the LVL to width, bevel the edge about 10 degrees+ approx. 1/3 the 1 3/4" edge so it does not hang on the bottom sill plate when the block is paced into the upper corner where the rim joist meets the subfloor and driven in along the bottom edge. Still use a protector block. Make sure the sill plate is really clean before either approach is used